# Extracting Values from a colon seperated varchar then looping through to insert data to a database

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am uploading data to a database from a form in Oracle Apex.
The form uploads data for a single department (11 rows with a PL/SQL process) but I want duplicate for multiple departments using a multiple item select list.

The select list returns a colon separated varchar2. (IE 856:456:455:455)
These numbers represent a department ID which will be the only change in each record uploaded,all other rows will be duplicated.

I'm thinking I need to split the varchar2 by colon in to an array, then loop through the array to upload each to the database along with the other 10 columns which will not change.

I have tried a couple of split methods to transform the colon separated values to comma separated values but nothing has worked. Couldn't find a string to array method either in Pl/SQL. I'm guessing it will be a little more complex than that.

```
l_input varchar2(4000) := :P4_ADDITIONAL_LE ||':'|| :P4_LEGAL_ENTITY_ID;
```

This is the only code I have which adds the initial dept to the addition depts. chosen from the select list. I have uploaded this to a test table and it is outputting 861:842:882:844:843. I want each of these values to be available for a separate upload using a for loop in a PL/SQL process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to split such strings, here is an example with `xmltable` where I put elements into collection and iterate through it:

```
declare 
  type tbl_var is table of varchar2(5);
  v_deps tbl_var;
  v_str varchar2(100) := '861:842:882:844:843';
begin 
  select trim(column_value) text
    bulk collect into v_deps
    from xmltable(('"' || replace(v_str, ':', '","') || '"'));

  for i in 1..v_deps.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(v_deps(i));
  end loop;
end;
```

Output:

```
861
842
882
844
843
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the API APEX_STRING.SPLIT for this. It is available from Apex 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is using a regular expression which can actually be combined with the other columns mentioned to complete the whole process in 1 SQL statement:

```
Insert into table_name(dept_no,col1,col2,col3)
with source as (select '861:842:882:844:843' str, 'aaa' colA, 'bbb' colB, 'ccc' colC from dual)
select regexp_substr(str,'[^:]+', 1, level) dept_id ,colA, colB, colC from source
     connect by regexp_substr(str, '[^:]+', 1, level) is not null;
```